# PHP exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a php pdo script  where I want to select the record (from a table in a MySQL database) with the highest number in "field5". I also have a few other constrictions, see below:

```
 $stmt=$db->query("SELECT `field1`,`field2` FROM ".$tablename." WHERE
 `field3`!=".$variable1." AND `field3`!=".$variable2." AND
 `field4`='xx' AND `field5`<".$variable3." ORDER BY DESC `field5` LIMIT
 1");
```

I have pretty much all the code inside a try-statement, and in the catch statement I use

```
var_dump($ex->getMessage());
```

to get the exception message from the exception $ex.

Now, when I execute the code I get the following exception message:

> 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC `field5`
>   LIMIT 1' at line 3' (length=232)

I'd be grateful for any advice on what might be wrong!

Comment: Oh god, please use prepared statements if you're already using PDO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
ORDER BY DESC field5
```

into

```
ORDER BY field5 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) for the syntax of select query. You have made a simple mistake which is, the query was *syntactically wrong*. You can only order the column by referencing it initially :

`ORDER BY '{Column-Name}'`

and then only you can define how it can be ordered either in ASC or DESC.

`ORDER BY '{Column-Name}' [ASC|DESC]`

So you have to change the query as shown here :

```
$stmt=$db->query("SELECT `field1`,`field2` FROM ".$tablename." WHERE
 `field3`!=".$variable1." AND `field3`!=".$variable2." AND
 `field4`='xx' AND `field5`<".$variable3." ORDER BY `field5` DESC 
LIMIT 1");
```